# What was Ferb’s secret identity?

Tags: phineas-and-ferb

A while ago, I watched the Phineas and Ferb movie where they go to another dimension. When they found out Perry's identity, Phineas asked if anyone else had a secret identity. Ferb raised his hand. What is his secret identity?

Comment: If we casually talked about it it wouldn't be much of a secret, would it?

Answer (score 4):

Ferb's secret identity is the lower half of **[The Beak](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/The_Beak_(suit))**.

The Beak is a superhero exoskeleton power armor suit with jetpacks that Phineas and Ferb create in the season 2 episode titled [*The Beak*](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/The_Beak).  That episode predates *Phineas and Ferb the Movie: Across the 2nd Dimension*.  Phineas and Ferb wear the suit together, Phineas piloting the upper half and Ferb the lower half.  The suit was originally intended for more peaceful purposes.  But during the suit's construction, a supervillain attacked Danville, so Phineas and Ferb decided to protect Danville and battle the supervillain in the unfinished suit.

Phineas decides in this episode that if they have to fight against supervillains, then he has to keep his identity as The Beak secret from everyone, and especially from Isabella, or else the villains might make Isabella a target.

> We can't tell Isabella were the Beak right now, that will put her in danger. The life of a superhero is a lonely one, Ferb.

So Phineas spends the rest of the episode as a comedic Superman quickchange routine, alternately meeting news reporter Isabella as The Beak and talking to him as Phineas.  At the end of the episode, Phineas does reveal to Isabella that he was The Beak.  However, The Beak may still count as a secret identity for both Phineas and Ferb enough that Ferb would put his hand up.  The Beak suit can be seen later in the movie, though that time it's not Phineas and Ferb riding it.